# court smell -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the song [Memory](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/barbrastreisand/memory.html):

> When the dawn comes
>   Tonight will be a memory too
>   And a new day will begin
>   Burnt out ends of smoky days
>   The stale **court smell** of morning
>   A street lamp dies
>   Another night is over
>   Another day is dawning

How do you understand that?

Comment: I clicked on the link hoping this would be a Nicki Minaj track. If it were, I could've just said that lyrics these days don't make sense like it used to, back when music was golden.

Comment: But mornings are supposed to be about freshness and a new beginning, right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a **typo**! (of sorts)

> The ***still*** **cold smell** of morning [here](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/b/barbra+streisand/memory_20012982.html)
>
> The ***stale*** **cold smell** of morning [here](http://www.lyricsmania.com/memory_cats_lyrics_andrew_lloyd_webber.html)

Comment: Oh, that 'eureka' moment! :o (+1) Thanks for this!

Comment: Strange there's so many different versions of that **one** line.